# Convert PDF/DOC/DOCx to Images in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, pdf, imagemagick, minimagick

**Part 1:** I have PDFs, Docs,Docx stored in my S3. When I download them I want them to first be converted to images (png or jpg) and then only download (as images or a thumbnail of images).
How to achieve this ?

**Part 2:** I have used **mini-magick** to convert pdf to image and its somewhat working like this:

```
require "mini_magick"

im=MiniMagick::Image.open("path/to_my_pdf.pdf")
im.format("png", 0)
im.write("some_thumbnail.png")
```

The problem here is a pdf can have multiple pages and I need each and every page to be converted into image format (may be an array of images) and I am not able to achieve it. I am only able to convert any one of the page of the pdf. Stuck here. Kindly help.

Answer any part of the question as you like. !!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using [RMagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick) gem as following.

```rb
require 'RMagick'

pdf = Magick::ImageList.new("path/to_my_pdf.pdf")

pdf.each_with_index do |page, i|
  page.write "#{i}_thumbnail.png"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working. But need one more help. I'm getting results somewhat like this :
`[/home/sher/Desktop/HarshaVardhan_Resume.pdf=>thumbnail-0.png PDF 612x792 612x792+0+0 PseudoClass 93c 8-bit 18kb, /home/sher/Desktop/HarshaVardhan_Resume.pdf=>thumbnail-1.png PDF 612x792 612x792+0+0 PseudoClass 80c 8-bit 18kb, /home/sher/Desktop/HarshaVardhan_Resume.pdf=>thumbnail-2.png PDF 612x792 612x792+0+0 PseudoClass 68c 8-bit 20kb, /home/sher/Desktop/HarshaVardhan_Resume.pdf=>thumbnail-3.png PDF 612x792 612x792+0+0 PseudoClass 93c 8-bit 14kb] scene=3` How do I get access to that png ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You mean the path to the png files?

Comment: Yes i want the path to that all the png so that I can access it and view it as I want !

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice helped me to convert .doc, .docx or .rtf to images.
Install LibreOffice on your server:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-common
sudo apt install libreoffice-writer
```

Test it in your terminal:

```
soffice --draw --convert-to pdf some_file.doc && convert -density 288x288 -units pixelsperinch some_file.pdf -background white -alpha background -alpha off -quality 100 -resize 25% img_name.png
```

As you see, this will first convert file to PDF and then to images.
You might need to edit ImageMagic policies:

```
# open ImageMagic policy
sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
# and add this line
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```